# Android System Webview usage

Tags: kotlin, webview, android-webview

I'm developing an app that contain an activity that showing a webpage, I've used a Webview to showing it. My webpage are require latest browser to open the content, some of my user are still using old phone which mean are still using old browser also. Currently, before loading the webpage I've checked the Webview version from the userAgentString of webview.

The question is, to update the Webview inside my app, do I ask to my user to update the [Chrome browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) or [Android System Webview](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview)?

I've tried ask the user to update the Chrome browser but my Webview still detected as old browser. I just need to know Webview on Kotlin are using chrome browser or android system webview, cause I've just knowing that some of android user are disabling or maybe not installing the android system webview